# Instrumentation of ARM Binaries

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, arm, llvm, jit

Lets say I've an Linux system running on a ARM processor. What are the current available tools for doing dynamic binary analyze/instrumentation? I was wondering if there is something like [Pin](http://www.pintool.org/) but for ARM binaries.

Comment: have your heard of any progress on this area lately?

Comment: Dynamic tools: [DynamoRIO](http://www.dynamorio.org/), [Dyninst](http://www.dyninst.org/). Static tools: http://www.ispras.ru/en/technologies/static_arm_binary_code_instrumentation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valgrind [supports ARM](http://www.valgrind.org/info/platforms.html). There also was [PIN for ARM](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/pinheads/message/8138) but it's been discontinued. You might be able to find an old copy, but it's likely won't support anything above ARMv5.

Comment: Oh, this is a shame. I decided to use llvm to instrument the program while it's still being compiled.